# How to optimally use Lexical as input in chat application?

Tags: javascript, lexicaljs

I am wondering how to implement Lexical as an input for a chat app. The issue lies in rendering the message list.

A naive approach would involve creating a common message editor component that wraps Lexical and all necessary plugins, with an `editable` prop. For the message input component, we would set `editable="true"`, and for each message, `editable="false"`. However, it's clearly suboptimal to have a whole editor instance for each message, especially when there could be hundreds of messages at a time. I haven't tested it yet, but I believe it would be a very resource-intensive approach.

The only alternative I could think of is to prerender HTML on save and store it in the database, but this has several caveats as well. It won't keep up with future editor updates, and there are concerns related to rendering HTML from user input, among other issues.

I believe this problem has likely been solved by someone already, and I would be glad to learn about better solutions.

Comment: You don't have to store the HTML in the database. You can still prerender the HTML whenever a message is fetched, to keep up with updates to the rendering behaviour (or be able to change it yourself). You can do that either on the backend or in the frontend (without editor instances).

Comment: "*it's clearly suboptimal to have a whole editor instance for each message*" - it's not as clear as you make it sound. How is this exactly? Have you measured it?

Comment: To add to what @Bergi said, a long while back a meta employee said (in the lexical discord) that at meta they simply set editable false. It's best to measure for yourself if it's acceptable though.

Comment: @FoolsWisdom yeah, I guess no need to prematurely overengineer stuff